# How to implement a vertical carousel in android

Tags: android, carousel

I am trying to figure out how to implement a vertical carousel in android  like a dialer look and feel in single view when user scroll up it will feel like a dialer view like the below image

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UTkFCT2A2BY/UUapxk1EvmI/AAAAAAAAX-Q/wHdlVYALMWw/s1600/2013-03-18+13.26.23.png

Comment: That image is simply a `TimePickerDialog`...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: yes it is datetime picker image but i need the same animation i need 3 different cards which keep changing like  DateTimePicker dialog. can you pls hep me out how to implemnet this

Comment: I would like to see what you have attempted first. For more information, please see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I appreciate your words sir, but here i am not sure which element to use to build this. I tried with view pagers using https://github.com/castorflex/VerticalViewPager but this kind of animation wasnt possible as view pager fragment comes one by one. here i need some idea how can i build this. I am new to this. Please sir help me out here

Comment: Carousels require good knowledge of the animation library. That I do not have, so can't help. There are only a few libraries that provide that feature.  https://android-arsenal.com/tag/154

Answer (score 0):

I would start with Recycler (with custom adapter if you need to generate items as user scrolls or with set of items if you know upfront)

All additional UI elements on "picker" can be done with `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`

And to do vertical scroll just use `LinearLayoutManager(context, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false)`